# conditional rendering at empty response of API in react js

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, conditional-rendering

I am building a little react js application where users can select a few filters and get response accordingly. For some values selected by users, nothing is found from database and I want to show "nothing found" message.

I tried using if & else conditional operators which is not producing results. Below is the code.

```
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.data.length){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h1>nothing found.</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            else{
            this.setState({ data: res.data,urlList:[] }) 
            console.log(this.state)  
            }                                                                    
        })
```

Now If I do this

```
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.data.length){
                console.log('nothing found')

            }
            else{
            this.setState({ data: res.data,urlList:[] }) 
            console.log(this.state)  
            }                                                                    
        })
```

I am getting a response on console. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a new state variable like

```
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          noData: ''
      }
 }
```

And here

```
   .then(res => {
        if(!res.data.length){
            this.setState({noData: 'nothing found'});
            console.log('nothing found')

        }
        else{
        this.setState({ data: res.data,urlList:[], noData: '' }) 
        console.log(this.state)  
        }                                                                    
    })
```

And in render just display this.state.noData

```
render(){
    return(
          <div>
               <h1>{this.state.noData}</h1>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: if I put this in render return then even while nothing is selected, this message would show up.

Comment: @Hemadari, Thanks a lot for helping. I ended up using your suggestion only in a little bit different way.

Comment: @Ruchit Dalwadi you are welcome. Please take a look at my updated answer. You can do in that way so nothing found will be displayed only when you select

Comment: perfect . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Log out the res.data object for a case when nothing is found. It may not be an empty array as your code assumes, but might contain some message to the effect that nothing on the database matches your query. You need to check for this rather than simply !res.data.

Comment: I did that only . for just the condition  !res.data.length I logged the data on console. and it is showing up on console but while I am returning the div, it is not showing up.